# Why do I receive Runtime error "91" in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a macro to crate a In/Out register for bar codes and i'm using a code i found online.
The problem is that when I insert a barcode, an error "91" pops up and highlights the line ActiveSheet.Range("a4:a150").Find("").Select
Im totally new to the coding world and have no idea whats wrong. would appreciate the help!

```
Sub access()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim foundVal As Range
Dim diff As Double
Dim rownumber As Long

barcode = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)
If barcode <> "" Then
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("a4:a150").Find(What:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
ActiveSheet.Range("a4:a150").Find("").Select
ActiveCell.Value = barcode
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = Date & "  " & Time
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) = ""
    Else
        rownumber = rng.Row
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(rownumber, 1), Cells(rownumber, 10)).Find("").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Date & "  " & Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) = ""
    End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line will throw an error if there are no empty cells in the range.